# Configure Android Studio for NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk

I have been trying to configure Android Studio to use `NDK` on `windows 7`. As a test I imported `hello-jni` projects from the samples.

I have done the following things -

1. Added ndk directory to `ndk.dir` in `local.properties` file.
2. In `settings>other settings>C/C++>Path` settings Additional include directories I have added paths to `<NDK install dir>/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/include` and `<NDK install dir>/sources/cxx-stl`
3. I also added a dummy.c file to shut up the error of no rule to make.

The 2nd step above took care of most of the errors that were being generated by android studio but some remained notably there were red underlines under `(*env)` and `NULL` wherever they were used. The project compiles perfectly and without complaints.

Another thing to note is that I am using `Ubuntu 14.04` at office where there are no errors in the ide and everything works smoothly while I am using `Windows 7` at home and I face the issues above.

Am I missing something here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what plugin are you using to get `settings>other settings>C/C++>Path` ? Android Studio doesn't understand C/C++ by default.

Comment: I am using CppTools plugin

Comment: I've also tried it and it's a really old plugin. I needed C++11 support and I've ended up using eclipse or visual studio instead to edit my native code. Do you have the other basic features working on your Windows installation ? like proper code completion ? to determine if it's completely failing or only partially.

Comment: as far as I can tell the code completion was not working on windows. but it works fine on linux.